# Unable to perfect center font awesome in Sketch 3

Tags: icon, sketch-app, alignment, web-fonts

I am making a small infographic on a website in sketch 3. I am using font-awesome and trying to center an icon in the middle of the circle.

[image]

But I realised it can't be done because there is a small space after the icon. See picture.

[image]

Therefore it is always a little bit on left. Does anybody have the same problem and maybe solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That small space is actually a pixel, no way you can center the icon unless you scale up/down one pixel of the image inside the icon.